# how to create a readme.md file dynamically from the command output linux

Tags: linux, shell, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

am tying automate server commands through gitlab ci and create a readme file from that

right now I have a GitLab cicd pipeline which will get the list of installed installed software's in Linux server and store it in a file

```
yum list installed >> softwarelist.txt
```

but I want to create a readme file dynamically from the output of the above commands for example

*readme file sample below*

```
# installed software's

nodejs2.0.0  
java8
```

can anyone guide me to implement a way to archive it  through gitlab pipeline or through shell script

Comment: Why don't you simply redirict the yum output to `readme` instead of `somftwarelist.txt`?

Comment: @user1934428 yes but i want to append two three output to the file like dev qa and prod so i want to do it dynamically

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _two three output_,  but `>>` **is** appending. You just build up your _readme_ incrementally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it could be done as a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# insert headline
echo '# Installed software' > softwarelist.md

# insert package list
yum list installed >> softwarelist.md

# insert markdown bulletpoints  
sed -i '2,$ s/^/- /g' softwarelist.md
```

This is what `softwarelist.md` will look like

---

## Installed software

- nodejs2.0.0
- java8
- anotherpackage1.0

---

Comment: thanks for the response is there any way to add other environment recourses at the bottom for example am gonna execute this pipeline over Dev, QA and prod  how to achieve that thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you're aiming for tbh. You can redirect all output from your shell to the file with `>>` as show above with the `yum` output.